# WPF FontSize style hangs / freezes / stops responding

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, themes, freeze

Right, so on my desktop the following very very simple code hangs / freezes when compiled and run on the framework 3.5

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="s1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"></Setter>
    </Style> 
</ResourceDictionary> 
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="adfasdf" Style="{StaticResource s1}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The issue here, as far as I am aware is the FontSize in the style that is applied to the control.  When I remove it, it's fine.

If I compile it in framework 4.0 on the same machine, it works.

It works on my laptop and probably everyone else's machine, just not on my desktop.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Hey everyone, I found a solution to this problem.  I had to stop the FontCache service for framework 3.0 and delete the font cache.dat file that I assume was corrupt.  See link below

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7cc032c1-5f4d-4518-adc6-f53afd051e6b

Answer (score 0):

The first impression is **Huh?!** Interesting. If you launch another instance of VS, attach to hung process, and click `Debug -> Break All`, what do you see?

Comment: The call stack shows

PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.FontCache.HashTable.Lookup(MS.Internal.FontCache.IFontCacheElement e, bool add) + 0x8d bytes

Comment: Depending when I stop, sometimes it's a bit further as shown below

PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.FontCache.ElementCacher.Mapping.get() + 0x33 bytes

Comment: Seems like there is an endless loop

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe it has something to do with presentation font cache service? What happens if you disable it?

Comment: :) Glad I could help, Jonathan